# Динамическое добавление правил маршрутизации Yii2

Tags: yii2, маршрутизация

Объясните новичку-новичку пожалуйста где я не правильно читаю докуцментацию?
Имеется:

- php 7.4
- свежепоставленный yii advanced.

в файле frontend\config\main.php
пишу:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'home' => '',
                'about' => 'site/about',
                'contact' => 'site/contact',
                'signup' => 'site/signup',
                'login' => 'site/login',
                'logout' => 'site/logout',
                'gii' => 'gii',
                'defaultRoute' => '']
        ]
```

Соответственно поправляю ссылки в файле frontend\views\layouts\main.php

Все работает!
в браузере ссылки выглядят как /contact, /signup, /about, /login
Все работает, ссылки ведут куда положено!

Читаю документацию по маршрутизации и динамичесвому добавлению правил, пытаюсь прикрутить.

В файле frontend\config\main.php
Ключ rules оставляю пустым массивом.

В файле frontend\config\bootstrap.php прописываю:

```
use yii\base\BootstrapInterface;

class Bootstrap implements BootstrapInterface
{
    function bootstrap($app)
    {
        $app->getUrlManager()->addRules(
            [
                'home' => '',
                'about' => 'site/about',
                'contact' => 'site/contact',
                'signup' => 'site/signup',
                'login' => 'site/login',
                'logout' => 'site/logout',
                'gii' => 'gii',
                'defaultRoute' => ''
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

получаю: Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Bootstrap has a deprecated constructor in ...

Вроде понятно, делаю function __construct($app) вместо function bootstrap($app)

получаю: Fatal error: Class Bootstrap contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (yii\base\BootstrapInterface::bootstrap) in...

Вроде тоже понятно, делаю abstract class Bootstrap... вместо class Bootstrap...

Ошибок не получаю, - уже хорошо.
Смотрю ссылки:

- about и contact (визуально) ведут на /site/about и site/contact и работают
- gii (визуально) ведет на /gii и работает
- signup и login (визуально) ведут на /signup и /login и уходят на 404.

Покажите пальцем, пожалуйста, где я чего не дочитал?